# Oracle 12c network connection issue

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I face the below error when i try to connect to the database

[image]

Comment: try hostname = localhost or the ip of the server where the database is installed

Comment: Are you sure about the port? 1588 is rather uncommon for Oracle